# Navigating word by word through TWebBrowser control (MSHTML)

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control, c++builder, twebbrowser

I am trying to navigate through MSHTML (TWebBrowser) document word by word for spell checking each word. But I have problems:

1) it selects words oddly - For example "Abc: def" - the selection is "Abc" as first and ":" as second word. Also, if a word ends with space for example "Abc def" it would select "Abc " with the trailing space included. Is there a way to select only what is the word and not the trailing spaces or non-word characters? Or is this the best `move` can offer and it is up to programmer to filter the words correctly?

2) Is there a way to specify which delimiters it will use for example only to let it use space as a delimiter and not colons, dashes or other characters? (Microsoft docs say - "Word - Moves one or more words. A word is a collection of characters terminated by a space or other white space character. ", but it also uses other delimiters, not just space, tabs and similar)

Current code is:

```cpp
bool SelectNext(bool firstonly = false)
    {
    DelphiInterface<IHTMLDocument2> diDoc = WB->Document;
    if (diDoc)
        {
        DelphiInterface<IHTMLSelectionObject> diSel = diDoc->selection;
        if (diSel)
            {
            if (firstonly) diSel->empty();

            if (diSel->type_ == "None" || diSel->type_ == "Text")
                {
                DelphiInterface<IDispatch> diRangeDisp;
                if (SUCCEEDED(diSel->createRange(diRangeDisp)) && diRangeDisp)
                    {
                    DelphiInterface<IHTMLTxtRange> diRange;
                    if (SUCCEEDED(diRangeDisp->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLTxtRange, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&diRange))) && diRange)
                        {
                        int Result;
                        unsigned short Res;
                        diRange->move("word", 1, Result);
                        diRange->expand("word", Res);
                        diRange->select();
                        return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return false;
    }

SelectNext(true); // Select the first "word"

// navigate first 200 words
for (int i = 0; i <= 200; i++)
    {
    SelectNext();
    // do spell checking of selected word here...
    }
```